# Unable to get proper response to change amazon page pincode

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to change the pincode of amazon page by sending  an API request from Python but it is showing the United States page instead of the India page.

I am using this code:

```python
import requests


headers = {
    'authority': 'www.amazon.in',
    'accept': 'text/html,*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'anti-csrftoken-a2z': 'hLaNTBVC/mkagq0BJS/W8TFb5VaZrt3CM8qrMciGN7ZVAAAAAGS4tS0AAAAB',
    'cookie': 'session-id=262-4494396-0955333; session-id-time=2082787201l; i18n-prefs=INR; ubid-acbin=261-0038112-8848703;',
    'device-memory': '8',
    'dnt': '1',
    'downlink': '1.5',
    'dpr': '1.25',
    'ect': '3g',
    'referer': 'https://www.amazon.in/',
    'rtt': '350',
    'sec-ch-device-memory': '8',
    'sec-ch-dpr': '1.25',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform-version': '"15.0.0"',
    'sec-ch-viewport-width': '714',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'viewport-width': '714',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

params = {
    'deviceType': 'desktop',
    'pageType': 'Gateway',
    'storeContext': 'NoStoreName',
    'actionSource': 'desktop-modal',
}

response = requests.get(
    'https://www.amazon.in/portal-migration/hz/glow/get-rendered-address-selections',
    params=params,
    headers=headers,
)
```

This is the desired result:

```
Feature requested to not be shown
Select a delivery location to see product availability and delivery options
Sign in to see your addresses
Delivery options may vary for different locations
Continue
or enter an Indian pincode
Apply
Please enter a valid pincode
This postcode is currently not available. Please close this window and try again.
or

Deliver outside India
Deliver outside India
```

Instead of getting this, I am being redirected to the United States page.

I have tried many ways but I am not getting any results.

Do you have any suggestions that may help me?